# Drawing a border around a set of vertices in Graphviz

Tags: graphviz

I am trying to draw a graph with Graphviz.

I wish to draw a dotted line around a set of vertices, symbolizing that they are a part of a bigger entity.

Say for example, if I have three vertices as eggs, chicken and ham, I should be able to draw a dotted line around all three of them, and label that border as food.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

It is possible to group nodes in graphviz by putting them into a **[cluster](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/lang.html)**. A cluster is a special kind of subgraph which certain layout engines (dot, fdp, ...) support, and if supported, the nodes in a cluster will be drawn together.

From the documentation:

> If the name of the subgraph begins with *cluster*, Graphviz notes the
>   subgraph as a special cluster subgraph. If supported, the layout
>   engine will do the layout so that the nodes belonging to the cluster
>   are drawn together, with the entire drawing of the cluster contained
>   within a bounding rectangle.
>
> Note that, for good and bad, cluster
>   subgraphs are *not* part of the DOT language, but solely a syntactic
>   convention adhered to by certain of the layout engines.

---

Important: **The ID of the subgraph has to start with `cluster`**.

---

Example:

```
graph g{
 subgraph cluster_food {
    eggs; chicken; ham;
    label="Food";
    graph[style=dotted];
 }
}
```

[image: ham, chicken and eggs]

Comment: So I'm guessing subgraph has no effect with dot, as I tried adding this and it has resulted in no changes at all. :(

Comment: @Trejkaz It works as displayed with dot. You should ask a question and specify the exact graph, command line and version of graphviz you're using.

Comment: Yeah, if I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong I will definitely post a new question.

Comment: @Trejkaz Did you figure it out? The `graph[style=dotted]` attribute does nothing for me either.

Comment: Ah, it's because it wasn't a *cluster*. @marapet, the `cluster_` prefix is apparently *not* just a convention; it is part of the syntax.

Comment: @jameshfisher It _is_ a convention used by certain layout engines, but it is _not_ part of the dot language. From the link in my answer: _Note that, for good and bad, cluster subgraphs are not part of the DOT language, but solely a syntactic convention adhered to by certain of the layout engines_ . The point of my answer was to show that the name of the subgraph **has** to start with `cluster`. I'll emphasize that in the answer.

Comment: Is it possible to control the justification of the label?

Comment: I don't believe `neato` supports clusters unfortunately.